# Redirect To Action with ID Parameter - .NetCore Web App MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, redirecttoaction

Need some help trying to redirect to a view.

I have a view/action called Jobs/Index
In short, this view grabs a list of employees and I have included a button for each employee to click on so they can view the jobs assigned to them. Each button executes Jobs/EmployeeJobs/Id, the ID depends on their staff ID.

I have a view/action which is jobs/EmployeeJobs/2.
This view shows a list of all jobs that are assigned to that staff member with an id of 2, but obviously will change depending on the staff member.

So, on that page I have my EDIT, DETAILS, and DELETE buttons. they're all working fine.
However when I try edit some job information and click save. my URL directs me to https://localhost:44327/Jobs.

When a user hits save I want to be redirected back to the view of that staff member such as
https://localhost:44327/Jobs/EmployeeJobs/2.

This is my EmployeeJobs/2 Action in my Jobs Controller

```
     `public async Task<IActionResult> EmployeeJobs(int? id)
    {
                    var jobs = await _context.Jobs
       .Include(j => j.Clients)
       .Include(j => j.Employees)
       .Include(j => j.Stage1)
       .Include(j => j.Stage2)
       .Include(j => j.Substages)
       .Include(j => j.Substages2).Where(m => m.Employees.Id == id)
                   .ToListAsync();


        return View(jobs);

    }`
```

This is my Edit/5 Action in my Jobs Controller or (POST)

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,JobNumber,Address,ClientID,StaffId,Notes,Stage1Id,Stage2Id,SubstagesId,Substages2Id,ConceptRequired,ConceptScheduleDate,ConceptSent,RevisionReceived,RevisionCompleted,ConceptApproved,MarketingRequired,MarketingScheduleDate,MarketingSent,MarketingCompleted,RenderRequired,RendererId,RenderSent,RenderReceived,ResourceRequired,PlannerId,ResourceScheduleDate,ResourceSent,ResourceCommentsReceived,ResourceCommentsCompeted,ResourceApproved,WorkingScheduleDate,WorkingCompleted,ReviewCompleted,TrussRequired,TrussId,TrussSent,TrussReceived,EngineerRequired,EngineerId,EngineerSent,EngineerReceived,ClientApprovalSent,ClientApprovalReceived,CouncilSubmission,CouncilId,BCNumber,RFIReceived,RFICompleted,BCGranted,AmendmentRequired,AmendmentScheduleDate,AmendmentCompleted,JobCompleted")] Jobs jobs)
    {
        if (id != jobs.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(jobs);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!JobsExists(jobs.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", new { id = id });
           //return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", new RouteValueDictionary(
            //    new { controller = "Jobs", action = "EmployeeJobs", id = id }));

        }

        return View(jobs);
    }
```

As you can see I have tried two methods multiple times or RedirectToAction. The weird thing is I can get the result I want of showing the jobs assigned to that employee when I am redirected if my code is
`return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", new { id = 2 });`

This code will take me back to the employee that has an ID of 2.
So hopefully someone can help me, please go easy on me I'm fairly new to coding

This is the relevant info from my Jobs Model

```
    public class Jobs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Number")]
    [Required]
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    // FK
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    [ForeignKey("Clients")]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    // FK
    [Display(Name = "Employee")]
    [ForeignKey("Employees")]
    public int StaffId { get; set; }


    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }



}
```

This is the code from my Employees Model

```
public class Employees
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8)]
    [Required]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the error in you Index action, when you are querying the database.

This is why it can't return new view. You are mixing `employeeId` with `jobId`. For id=2 you have an employee with Id =2 , so why it is working only for id=2;

And your index action has a very confusing query, and it is not async.

Try this

```
var jobs = await _context.Jobs
       .Include(j => j.Clients)
       .Include(j => j.Employees)
       .Include(j => j.Stage1)
       .Include(j => j.Stage2)
       .Include(j => j.Substages)
       .Include(j => j.Substages2)
       .Where(m =>  m.Employees.Id == id)
       .ToListAsync();

return View(jobs);
```

but I was wondering how this could be even compiled

```
  .Include(j => j.Employees)
      .....
  .Where(m =>  m.Employees.Id == id)
```

Is Employees one person?

UPDATE

After seeing your Job class I think your where is ok, but you can use this too

```
 .Where(m =>  m.StaffId == id)
```

and fix your Edit action

```
 return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", new { id = job.StaffId });
```

now it should be working

Comment: Mmmh sorry, that didn't work either. you could try reading my comment I left on Rahatur's response. I explained it a little bit more. Perhaps I am trying something that doesn't work at all which is my bad for being such a beginner. I might not have the best understanding of it. But I must say thank you though you gave me the correct code to make is async now haha I was wondering how to change it so thanks!!

Comment: @AlistairTrotter I see  m.Employees.Id == id . Is it compiled?  Please post Job class

Comment: Employees is referencing the Employees table within that table I have multiple employees with different employees each having their own ID/primary key

Comment: Could you post Job and Employees classes pls?

Comment: Sure thing, just added it now, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You said if you hard code the Id like the following then it is working:

```
return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", new { id = 2 });
```

Then try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("EmployeeJobs", "Jobs", new { id = jobs.StaffId });
```

Comment: Hi Rahatur, mmh, I still seem to be getting the same result. nothing showing up. Perhaps I could try explain a bit more. When this RedirectToAction is run, with new { id = jobs.Id}. It applies the ID of the job in question. not the Employee ID in question. I want to employee ID to go in there from the action EmployeeJobs not the ID from Jobs. I beleive this action is grabbing the current Job.Id and placing it in there. not the ID from the other table. Hope that makes sense

Comment: You have shared the job class. Based on that, instead of using the `jobs.id` you can use the `jobs.StaffId`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try returning an empty view without necessarily passing an argument to it like so

```
 return View();
```

Comment: Why would he load the `Edit` view again by returning an empty view? Clearly mentioned in the question - he wants to go to another page/action!